# How to make TypeScript conditional never types more usable?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on an application with a deeply complex type system (not changeable). It uses a lot of nested conditional never types to reject incorrect arguments.

Here is a very simplified example:

```js
type Never<T extends string> = never;

type CheckSmallDog<T> = T extends {woof: unknown}
  ? SmallDog
  : T extends {woof: unknown}
  ? Never<'not-smalldog'>
  : Never<'not-dog'>;

type Animal = {};

interface Cat extends Animal {
  meow(): void;
}

interface SmallDog extends Animal {
  woof(): void;
}

interface BigDog extends Animal {
  bark(): void;
}

// note the compiler reports the types in comments at the end of each line:
type BigDogCheck = CheckSmallDog<BigDog>; // never
type SmallDogCheck = CheckSmallDog<SmallDog>; // SmallDog
type CatCheck = CheckSmallDog<Cat>; // never
```

What I'd like to achieve is instead of the compiler reporting 'never' for the non SmallDog types, it provides more detail on why the type failed, in this example the value in the Never type would be useful, open to other ideas that would report through the compiler

Comment: I realize this is a stripped down example and you say you can't change it but what exactly is the point of all this? This *feels* like a design smell with the type hierarchy. I realize there's a case to be made for nominal types even in a structural system (e.g. sanitized vs unsafe user input) but this feels excessive to say the least.

Comment: @JaredSmith - I've just walked into this codebase (it's huge) so don't have context on the history unfortunately

Comment: I'm sorry then. I'd need to see the actual code to be sure but this kinda looks like somebody read a medium post on phantom types and sprinkled them throughout the codebase without really understanding how they work or whether that was a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to how `never` works in TS, you can't really attach any value to it: `never` will be dropped from any union type (`never | T` -> `T`) and will absorb any other types in intersection (`never & T` -> `never`). And `type Never<T extends string> = never` won't work because TS will simplify types, thus stripping type parameter if it's not used in type.

If you need `Never<T>` to be exactly `never`, then I think you don't have any options to attach any message to it. This might be fixed by [invalid type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) in future, but not today.

You can attach message to never by omiting part of it and then doing intersection like this:

```js
type Never<T extends string> = Omit<never, T> & {__message: T};

type CheckSmallDog<T> = T extends {woof: unknown}
  ? SmallDog
  : T extends {bark: unknown}
    ? Never<'not-smalldog'>
    : Never<'not-dog'>;

type Animal = {};

interface Cat extends Animal {
  meow(): void;
}

interface SmallDog extends Animal {
  woof(): void;
}

interface BigDog extends Animal {
  bark(): void;
}

type BigDogCheck = CheckSmallDog<BigDog>; // Omit<never, "not-smalldog"> & { __message: "not-smalldog"; }
type SmallDogCheck = CheckSmallDog<SmallDog>; // SmallDog
type CatCheck = CheckSmallDog<Cat>; // Omit<never, "not-dog"> & { __message: "not-dog"; }
```

However, this will modify behavior, so `Never<T>` and `never` will behave differently which might not be suitable for your application.